# ProgressBar Dialog not showing

Tags: android

I am new to Android development and am facing a slight issue. My first screen is a basic log in screen. There is a LOG IN button on the screen and a OnClickHandler implemented for the button.
When the user clicks the log in button i validate the user name and password, shows a ProgressBar dialog start a new Thread. The thread connects to the server and validates the user info. The problem is that the Progress Bar doesn't show until after the thread has finished. I read that all work must be done in a separate thread otherwise the Progress Bar will not see the light of day and i am doing my work in a separate thread.

But the problem is that right below the thread code i have a loop while(userinfo==null){} . This is because the userinfo object is been populated by the newly created thread and the userinfo object is required by code below the thread, without the loop a new thread would be created that fills the userinfo object but in the mean time the code that reads the userinfo would get a null object. If any one is willing to review the code i could send the file that has this code. Really need some help in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) helpful. Do whatever it is you do in the loop in postexecute instead.